# Valgrind ==16958== invalid write of size 4

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-errors, valgrind

[valgrind message]

```
==16958== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==16958== Invalid read of size 4
==16958==    at 0x109637: arr_del (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/lab3/lab3)
==16958==    by 0x10939D: main (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/lab3/lab3)
==16958==  Address 0x4a19938 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==16958==    at 0x483E7CF: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16958==    by 0x109541: arr_corr (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/lab3/lab3)
==16958==    by 0x109323: main (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/lab3/lab3)
```

[functions code]

```
int main(){
    int input=0;
    int *arr;
    int s;
    size_t index;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    switch(input){
    case 2:
        scanf("%zu", &index);
        arr = arr_corr(arr, index, &s);
        arr_output(arr, s);
        break;

    case 3:
        scanf("%zu", &index);
        arr = arr_del(arr, index, &s);
        arr_output(arr, s);
        break;
    }
}

int* arr_corr(int *arr, size_t index, int *s){
    int n;
    (*s) = (*s)+1;
    arr = (int*) realloc(arr, (size_t)(*s) * sizeof(int));
    for(size_t i = (size_t)((*s)-1); i>=index; i--){
        arr[i+1] = arr[i];
    }
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr[index]= n;
    return arr;
}

int* arr_del(int *arr, size_t index, int *s){
    for(size_t i=index; i<(size_t)(*s); i++){
        arr[i]=arr[i+1];
    }
    (*s)=(*s)-1;
    arr = (int*) realloc (arr, (size_t)(*s) * sizeof(int));
    return arr;
}
```

I just don't understand what this message means and what I did wrong. Pls help me! Everything I know is that there is no problem with main() function and with anything else. The code is located in two files. There is also no problem with linking these files.

Comment: Please post everything in plain text. No links, no images. And please bother to add some context, such as what you've tried, what problems you've encountered, and what steps you've taken as part of your investigation.

Comment: You haven't shown the `arr_del` function which is probably where the error is. You should show a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't do anything to it because i just can't understand the valgrind's message. I'm not good enough in this sphere, so I can't even find the information which I will understand

Comment: The errors also originate in main and arr_del. Post them.

Comment: You are reading the value of the variable `s`, but it has not been initialized.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it was initialized in another function, in which i use malloc

Comment: You may think it was, but it wasn't. The variable `s` is local to `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
==16958==  Address 0x4a19938 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==16958==    at 0x483E7CF: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

You realloc'd something of size 24 bytes (6 `int`s).

```
==16958== Invalid read of size 4
==16958==    at 0x109637: arr_del (in /home/students/s/smelov.vp/lab3/lab3)
```

You tried to read beyond the end of that memory (bytes 24 to 27, or the int array at index 6).

It would be clearer if you compiler your code with debug information (-g).

To fix this you either need to allocate more memory or do something like change your loop control so that you stop sooner and don't read too far.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was true that I tried to read beyond the end of the memory. The thing was that 
`for(size_t i = (size_t)((*s)-1); i>=index; i--){
        arr[i+1] = arr[i];
    }`
sometimes readed the element of array which doesn't exist :)

Comment: Everything i needed was to put `...{arr[i]=arr[i-1]}` instead (in arr_corr) and `... {arr[i-1]=arr[i]}` (in arr_del)